# the GameObject rotates incorrectly on the z-axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

there is a circle, it needs to be rotated by pressing the button, with a certain speed along the z axis, and when it turns 90, the rotation will stop, but for some reason the rotation is not working properly

```
public GameObject Circle;

private bool RotationActive;

//rotation value at which the circle stops rotation
private float RotatePost;

private float RotationSpeed;

private float CircleRotateZ;

void Start()
{
    RotationActive = false;

    RotationSpeed = 0.5f;

    RotatePost = 90;
}

//function is bound to a button
public void RotateActive(){
    RotationActive = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (RotationActive == true)
    {
        CircleRotateZ = Circle.transform.rotation.z;

        //if the circle along the z axis is rotated more than Rotation Post...
        if (CircleRotateZ >= RotatePost )
        {
            RotatePost = CircleRotateZ + 90;
            RotationActive = false;
        }

        //assignment of a new coordinate
        Circle.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,RotationSpeed + CircleRotateZ));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to grab the rotation from the Quaternion which is not the angle of the object. Instead you should use:

```
CircleRotateZ = Circle.transform.eulerAngles.z;
```

Also the way you are currently rotating will make it speed up over time. The Rotate functions rotates the object by the amount, not to the amount given, so if you only want to rotate by the rotation speed you should use:

```
Circle.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, RotationSpeed));
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not working properly. You mean it doesn't move at all? If it doesn't move at all, check if you dragged the circle game object to the game object field in the Inspector. One more thing, why didn't you call the 'RotateActive' function?